# How can I force PostgreSQL to start after network is setup on Ubuntu Server 16?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, postgresql, boot

PostgreSQL fails to bind socket because it starts before network is setup.

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and PostgreSQL 9.5. I have read many docs over the internet but nothing solved my problem.

I am pretty sure that the problem is: **PostgreSQL service try to create a socket before Network Interface is properly setup.**

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service
● postgresql@9.5-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-07-27 09:42:36 UTC; 1min 43s ago
  Process: 5274 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 27 09:42:34 airpy-server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server postgresql@9.5-main[5274]: The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log outp
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server postgresql@9.5-main[5274]: 2016-07-27 09:42:36 UTC [5332-1] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socke
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server postgresql@9.5-main[5274]: 2016-07-27 09:42:36 UTC [5332-2] HINT:  Is another postmaster al
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server postgresql@9.5-main[5274]: 2016-07-27 09:42:36 UTC [5332-3] WARNING:  could not create list
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server postgresql@9.5-main[5274]: 2016-07-27 09:42:36 UTC [5332-4] FATAL:  could not create any TC
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 09:42:36 airpy-server systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I must use DHCP (and I cannot change it) with a fixed lease. Since I have set the `listen_address='fixed_ip'` into `postgresql.conf` the cluster does not start at boot. This is how everything started...

And I have wasted two days trying to make postgreSQL wait for Network configuration without success. It was working like a charm on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (I had nothing to configure) and now it just does not work for the new LTS release.

I have, at least, tried those leads:

- [Ubuntu-Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323253), it removed another errors (A start job is running for Raise of network interface...)
- [NetworkTarget](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/), it added other errors
  And my problem remains.

**How can I force PostgreSQL to start after network is setup on Ubuntu Server 16?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you manage to solve that? I'm running into the same issue (I want to wait for docker network to be available).

Comment: @Matthieu, yes I did after few weeks more documentation were available. Then I have modified my unit file, in order to wait for network.service

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer describing how you achieved it? It would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I would but I am busy right now.

Comment: @Matthieu added answer

Comment: @Matthieu, you are welcome. Does it work on your system?

Comment: Not quite yet. I don't have the unite file in `/etc/systemd/system/`. Seems I have to generate it like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265079/77489.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using new `systemctl` service manager, you can force service to wait for network is active until it starts. This is achieved by editing the service unit file (look in `/etc/systemd/system/`) and adding following lines in `unit` section:

```
[Unit]

Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

Then reload service with the new configuration:

```
systemctl reload name.service
```

Reboot the system to check it wait for network before starting service.

Answer (score 0):

In the service file `(/etc/init.d/<service>)` you can specify after which service PostGre must start. It would be like this :

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             sshd
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:    OpenBSD Secure Shell server
### END INIT INFO
```

In the Required-start you can specify `networking`

Comment: I already have a `$network` entry in this file. I think this kind of configuration is deprecated because now it is `systemctl` which handle it using service units.